# Where can I get data on released inmates in the US?

Tags: data-request, usa

I'm dealing with a small rural town where a common belief is that a significant number of former inmates are resettled after their release from prison. I've examined proxies for this by looking at probation budgets, and other related services compared to the rest of the state. I feel that the proxies I'm using could be unconvincing and would like more direct data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are data sets that you may not be aware of at [BJS](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dca) including

1. [1995 Survey of Adults on Probation](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=257) (SAP) 
   This Bureau of Justice Statistics survey is the first nationally representative survey of probationers. The collection detailed information on the characteristics of probationers through a review of probationers' administrative records and personal interviews with probationers.
2. [2006 Census of State Parole Supervising Agencies](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=258) 
   The 2006 Census of State Parole Supervising Agencies collected data from parole supervising organizations about the organizational structure of the agencies, staffing, supervision levels of offenders, and whether the parole agency had a role in considering prisoners for release, setting the conditions of supervision, and conducting parole revocation hearings. This collection was conducted one time in 2006. The census was sent to 68 respondents, including 50 central state reporters, the California Youth Authority, and the District of Columbia. Sixteen local Minnesota Community Corrections Act agencies were asked to provide information on staffing and supervision not available from the state.
3. [Annual Probation Survey and Annual Parole Survey](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=271) 
   Collect data from probation and parole agencies in the U.S. on an annual basis. Data include the number of adults on state and federal probation and parole at the beginning and end of each year, the number of adults entering and exiting probation and parole supervision during the year, and the characteristics of adults under the supervision of probation and parole agencies.